# How to skip certain folder in Get-ChildItem command

Tags: powershell

I want to search particular string on multiple files, here the command will do. This command will search all folders within AMT_Project. Now I want to skip folder Data Within AMT_Project folder. How can I do that ?

```
PS E:\User\AMT_Project> Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "+@QWEAz" -SimpleMatch | group path | select name
```

Folder structure

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invoke [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) twice. The first time, you get all items from the `E:\User\AMT_Project` directory, then you exclude the `Data` folder using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet and finally use the second [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet with the `-Recurse` switch to retrieve the files recursively:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\User\AMT_Project' | Where-Object Name -ne 'Data' | Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

You could also retrieve all items recursively first and filter them:

```
Get-ChildItems 'E:\User\AMT_Project' -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -NotMatch 'E:\\User\\AMT_Project\\Data\\.*'
```

Comment: Data folder is not a sub-folder for AMT_Project

Comment: You should have mentioned that within your question.. However, just use the second example and replace the match:`Get-ChildItems 'E:\User\AMT_Project' -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -NotMatch 'E:\\User\\AMT_Project\\.*?\\Data\\.*'`

Comment: Excellent.. Thanks